# Refer to objects in different index - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a zip-code table with list of zipcodes mapped to state. In state table, I have state name, state website, key locations etc. I am planning to store these two table values in elastic search populated using logstash.

My ES queries would be based on zipcode and result should return corresponding state and its information.

What is the best approach to store this kind of data. For ex: store zipcode as id and state info as values. In this approach, lot of duplicate data will be stored.

Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch, and indeed, NoSQL databases in general, get a big chunk of their advantages from not using foreign keys like SQL databases do.

Instead of referring to the State index, you should include all the State data in the Zip-Code index.  So, for example, if you have zip codes 10001 and 10005 in your ES database (both in New York), both should include the value "state", which itself includes the subvalues you listed for your state table.  This does duplicate data (because each entry for a zip code in the same state will have the same information in its 'state' value), but will increase speed relative to a SQL database (because you don't have to refer to a separate table).

Comment: I was also thinking along the same lines, but wanted to validate my thoughts and get experts view on this problem..